# Что значит вывести значение переданного параметра в закрытой функции в python и как его написать данную функцию?

Tags: python, ооп

При изучении основ я столкнулся с непониманием требования из задания. Вот его текст:

5. Сделайте закрытый метод printlog(), в котором с помощью функции print() выводите значение переданного параметра.

Понимаю, что вопрос глупый.
Спасибо заранее за проявленное сострадание

Comment: Не понятно, что значит _закрытый_ метод. Помимо обычных есть защищенный и есть приватный.

Comment: @SergFSM что то из перечисленного, это же на уровне терминалогии и надо обращаться к тому материалу откуда это задание. Кривые переводы, глоссарии вносят свою лепту)

Comment: @SergFSM да, кривой глаз читает, ну. Понятно, что ничего не понятно в вопросе. Ставлю на то, что это приватный. Кто бы рассудил?

Comment: Имеется ввиду приватный

Answer (score 1):

Видимо имеется ввиду, что в момент инициализации вы передаете какой-то параметр, и из инициализации сразу же вызывается метод его вывода. Выглядеть это может так:

```
class TestClass:
    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.arg = arg
        self._printlog()

    def _printlog(self):
        print(self.arg)

test_obj = TestClass("This is test")
```

Comment: А как можно выполнить тоже самое, только чтобы вместо public "arg" был private "__arg"?

Comment: @DeBut просто прописать не self.arg = arg, а self.__arg = arg